# Style broken when publishing explicit actions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, action

I have an application with defined actions and objects; those actions are explicitly shared (`fb:explicitly_shared = true`).

Everything works as expected, but, when I see the post on the News Feed I don't see the model that I see when editing the object (trough the preview), instead I see a much bigger picture in the News Feed.

I've attached 2 images, showing the normal style and the abnormal style of the same exact post. This behavior only happens in the news feed. Time line is always OK.

Normal:
https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/Z5cXJlOR6eRO6Af0PC_ZPNMTjNZETYmyPJy0liipFm0?feat=directlink

Abnormal:
https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/TrVV4CCBUoptIIoee4lVKNMTjNZETYmyPJy0liipFm0?feat=directlink

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That's the expected behaviour for explicitly shared content.

Comment: thanks four your answer, but this behaviour it's completely random for me. can you explain when each view is showed?